# PGFplots: scatter using 'colormap access=direct' results in PGF Math Error

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like to produce a scatter plot using `pgfplots` with points belonging to different classes.
The point colors should be determined through a class column in the data, which refers to an index in a colormap.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{colormap={mymap}{
rgb=(0.8,0.0,0.0)
rgb=(0.0,0.8,0.0)
rgb=(0.0,0.0,0.8)
}}

    \begin{axis}
        \addplot [
            scatter,
            mark=*,
            only marks,
            point meta=\thisrowno{2},
            % colormap access=direct   % NB
        ] table {
            0 0 0
            1 1 1
            2 2 0
        };

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

So far, the color mapping works as a **linear map**. That means:

- The outer points are rendered red (lowest meta value => lowest color value)
- The inner point is rendered blue (highest meta value => highest color value)

I'd like to use the colormap as a **color palette**, so that I can *directly specify* the used color, regardless of other points' meta value:

- The outer points should be rendered red (meta value 0 => pick color 0 from colormap)
- The inner point should be rendered green (meta value 1 => pick color 1 from colormap)

The documentation includes an example ("Lena" image), using `colormap access=direct`.
It seems that it's exactly what is needed:

> The choice "direct" does not perform any transformation; it interprets the value of `point meta` as integer indices into the current color map.

However, when activated, I get the following error:

> Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '0.8,0.0,0.0' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near ',0.0,0.0'..

There is a slew of further errors, including `Runaway argument?`, but I deem them subordinate to the root error.

The error does not occur if `colormap access=direct` is commented out.
The problem occurs with pdflatex, lualatex on TeX Live 2019; I also ran this on Overleaf, which uses pdflatex on TeX Live 2020, resulting in the same error.

---

I can think of a workaround: split the data into separate classes myself, and use one `\addplot` per class, specifying the corresponding color individually. That seems cumbersome.

Do you know why the error comes up? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ask me too much why, but after reading the `pgfplots` manual trying to find out why your example doesn't work, I discovered that `colormap access=direct` works fine here if one uses `\addplot[point meta=explicit symbolic, ...] table[meta index=2] ...`. Using `explicit` instead of `explicit symbolic` brings back the same error as in your example. I find this is a bit strange, because in the `matrix plot` example from the manual that is used to illustrate `colormap access=direct` (see section *Using Colormaps as Indexed Color Space (Palette)* on p. 236 in `Revision 1.17 (2020/02/29)` of the manual), the point meta is treated *numerically* with `point meta=explicit`. It would appear that `scatter` doesn't handle `point meta` in the same way as `matrix plot`.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{colormap={mymap}{
  rgb=(0.8,0.0,0.0)
  rgb=(0.0,0.8,0.0)
  rgb=(0.0,0.0,0.8)
}}

\begin{axis}
    \addplot [
        scatter,
        mark=*,
        only marks,
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
        colormap access=direct,
    ] table[meta index=2] {
        0 0 0
        1 1 1
        2 2 0
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that it is not necessary to provide indices in the colormap definition with this solution: it does yield

> 0 0.8 0 rg

for the middle point in the PDF stream, *without* any need to use the following syntax from [your answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/568170/73317):

```
rgb(0)=(0.8,0.0,0.0)
rgb(1)=(0.0,0.8,0.0)
rgb(2)=(0.0,0.0,0.8)
```

It is not necessary to provide `point meta min` or `point meta max` either. The palette appears to be used in a straightforward way.

Answer (score 0):

Using `point meta min` and `point meta max` keys, we can spread the range of used color indices, giving us a mapping independent of what meta values actually occur in the data.
That means that the middle point is in fact rendered green:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{colormap={mymap}{
rgb=(0.8,0.0,0.0)
rgb=(0.0,0.8,0.0)
rgb=(0.0,0.0,0.8)
}}

    \begin{axis}
        \addplot [
            scatter,
            mark=*,
            only marks,
            point meta=\thisrowno{2},
            point meta min=0,
            point meta max=2, % the max color of the colormap
        ] table {
            0 0 0
            1 1 1
            2 2 0
        };

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

---

We could leave it here, but inspecting the generated PDF shows a slightly wrong green for the middle point:

> 0.00004 0.79995 0 rg

Using colormap coordinates helps here:

```
\pgfplotsset{colormap={mymap}{
rgb(0)=(0.8,0.0,0.0)
rgb(1)=(0.0,0.8,0.0)
rgb(2)=(0.0,0.0,0.8)
}}
```

Giving us:

> 0 0.8 0 rg

Note that this last addition in itself (using colormap coordinates) is not a fix to the original problem, even if combined with `colormap access=direct`.